# Flying helicopters in GTA IV using the keyboard

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-iv

Short of buying a gamepad, what can I do to improve my control of helicopters using the keyboard in GTA IV - The Ballad of Gay Tony? I am stuck on a mission where I have to blow up a yacht and then chase and take out three moving boats. Whenever I press a key, the movement becomes too much to handle and compensating for it causes me to spiral into a watery death.

I am using the default controls for flying:

- Number pad 4/6 for left and right rotation
- W/S for altitude
- A/D for banking left and right
- Mouse 1 for shooting

I turned off mouse control for helicopters in favor of the keyboard as this would just aggravate my control (or lack of it) when flying.

Comment: I'm also flying with your setup.
Using WS for altitude, AD for banking and 9 and 3 I believe for going forwards / backwards.

Comment: Actualy after some time chasing em.
They stop in a small beach.
And then theyll be running on the ground.
Much easyer(but stilldont get off the heli).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have experience with GTA IV, but it sounds similar to the controls/physics for Vice City:

1. Don't hold the keys down as much, try tapping more. This will give you more incremental steering until you get used to the controls a bit more.
2. Finish your turns early, there's usually a bit of inertia that will keep you banking.
3. Relax, you're going to be more tense when you feel clumsy, take a few attempts and mess up on purpose just to get a feel for the heli, crashing into buildings/water, flipping upside-down etc.

Comment: The keyboard controls are pretty much the same across all GTA PC versions.